# Create multiple model objects using contents of an array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have the following array:

```
[['a'],['b'],['c']]
```

I would like to create 3 new rows in my table... Let's call the table 'Letters'

So I would have the following

```
id  name
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Is there anyway to do this in rails, in a single step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
letters.flatten.map{|letter| Letter.create(:name => letter)}
```